# How do you change a Text field .onTapGesture (Swift5, Xcode12.4)?

Tags: swift5, xcode12

Seemingly simple but I can't seem to find any results on this.

I have this code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var MinimalTimer: MinimalistTimer = MinimalistTimer()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("\(MinimalTimer.fourteenMinutes)")
            .onTapGesture {
                MinimalTimer.decrementTimer()
            }
    }
}
```

and I want to tap the timer and display on the text the new time, e.g. 840 -> 839 -> 838.

How do you change the display text on tap?

[Timer example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I2Iw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this will work in swiftUI though but try , MinimalTimer.addGestureRecognizer(<#T##gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer##UIGestureRecognizer#>) there is method something like this , you'll get it with autoComplete
Look for gesture Recogniser

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and see how far I can get.